# Is there any way of having TinyMCE options selected by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Say I want to have the 'bold' option selected by default when the editor is initialized. How would I do that?

**EDIT:** A solution working with what Thariama answered is the following. I discovered that having the `<p>` tag left in there screwed with selecting other options, like with different headlines, and as I have no need for a `<p>` tag in this particular editor I did this in order to get `<h1>` by default:

```
setup: function(ed) { 
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
        if ($('p', ed.getDoc()).length > 0) {
            $('p', ed.getDoc()).remove();
            $('<h1><br mce_bogus="1" /></h1>').appendTo($('body', ed.getDoc()));
        }
    });
}
```

This works great even when the user jumps between selection options in a select.

**EDIT2:** This seems to work if you do need the `<p>` tag. This makes it **bold** by default:

```
setup: function(ed) { 
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
        if ($('p', ed.getDoc()).children().length == 1 && $('p', ed.getDoc()).children(':first').is('br')) {
            $('p', ed.getDoc()).html('<b><br mce_bogus="1" /></b>');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure of choice depends on many factors. If you have an empty tinymce editor you can initialize your editor with the following content

```
<p><strong><strong></p>
```

Please update your question regarding your use case.

**EDIT:**  This might work better for you. Add this handler to one of your own plugins.
It checks for all paragraphs (if your tinymce uses divs you need to alter this piece of code)
and wraps the inner HTML into b-tags (you might want to use strong-tags).

```
    ed.onInit.add(function(ed){
        ps = ed.getDoc().getElementsByTagName('p');
        for (var i=0; i < ps.length ; i++) {
            ps[i].innerHTML = '<b>'+ps[i].innerHTML+'</b>';
        }
    });
```

Another option you have is to not use an own plugin, but to use the setup parameter when initializing tinymce:

```
setup : function(ed) {

    ed.onInit.add(function(ed){
        ps = ed.getDoc().getElementsByTagName('p');
        for (var i=0; i < ps.length ; i++) {
            ps[i].innerHTML = '<b>'+ps[i].innerHTML+'</b>';
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Well it could be empty, it could initialize with content. I am using something like what you are suggesting now except with the tags being empty like that it hasn't worked for me. I have been using a zero-width space (8203) in the middle which works but causes other problems which is why I'd like to not use that approach. Additionally, with this approach the options in the toolbar aren't being used which really should be possible. I'd really just like to trigger the options at some point after editor initialization just as if the user had clicked the option.

Comment: You are right cris, you did the right thing inserting a space character. I edited my post, the solution presented should solve your problem in an elegant manner.

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing it when the user enters it, why not output the values inside a bold tag when you output the data to the user outside of tinyMCE?  That way, the user has no ability to override the option as they would if you simply had a  tag inside.

As an aside, if you're using TinyMCE for a wysiwg web editor in an environment where users first generate code in Microsoft Word, there are significant issues with getting "junk" word code in via paste.  Tiny's solution is a "paste from word" button, which users seem to often ignore -- I've deployed Tiny in 50+ business websites, and it's been a major issue with a majority of the clients using those sites.  I switched over to CKEditor, which does word code-stripping on the FRONT end, and all's been well.  People have their preferences, and I even liked using Tiny more.  But Word Code issues have become a dealbreaker for me and I won't install Tiny any more.

Comment: i solved the paste issues using the preprocess option and filtering the pasted content there by myself (but were some issues to be solved before that was possible)

Comment: The user is free to not have it bold but I'd like the editor to default to that setting. And as it is WYSIWYG it would be odd not to have changes display in the editor if that is what you are suggesting. Oh and preaching to the choir when it comes to TinyMCE and pasting from word. Many a regular expression has been used to deal with that, even with the plugin.